# Final topology on Y

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have the following surjective map $p : X \rightarrow Y$, let X have the $\psi$ complement topology, where $\psi$ infinite cardinal what is the final topology on Y with respect to the quotient topology ?

I found that when X is countable then it will be the discrete topology, but I have no idea what if X is uncountable ?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think it will be the discrete topology all the time, but I am not sure how can I prove it.

Comment: @D_S any help what do you think ?

Comment: Maybe try some examples?  If you take $X = \mathbb{R}$, and the topology where $A \subseteq X$ is open iff its complement is finite or countable, and you define $p: X \rightarrow Y = \mathbb{N}$ by $$p(n) = n+1 : n \in \mathbb{N}$$ $$p(x) = 1 : x \not\in \{1, 2, ... \} $$ then it looks like the open sets of $Y$ consist of empty set and all subsets which contain $1$.  So this isn't the discrete topology in this case.

Comment: but then we would have to look at every map and see what it is.

Comment: Let's write $\kappa$ not $\psi$ for the infinite cardinal, it's way more normal. Do you mean that the topology on $X$ is the co-$\kappa$ topology, open sets are $\emptyset, X$, and subsets whose complements have cardinality $<\kappa$?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I mean

Comment: OK so the topology on $Y$ will be all $U\subseteq Y$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ has complement of card $<\kappa$. That is, $X\setminus p^{-1}(U) = p^{-1}(Y\setminus U)$ has card $<\kappa$.

Comment: Is there a more description to that topology ?

Comment: That's not an answer actually :) Just rephrasing it to get a handle on it.

Comment: I mean can we completely classify what is the topology on Y ?

Comment: yeah that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\kappa$ denote the infinite cardinal. The topology on $X$ is the co-$\kappa$ topology, whose open sets are $\emptyset, X$, and all subsets $U\subseteq X$ such that the cardinality of the complement of $U$ is less than $\kappa$: $\lvert X\setminus U\rvert < \kappa$.

By definition, the topology on $Y$ has as its open sets all $V\subseteq Y$ such that $p^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. That is,

> $V\subseteq Y$ is open $\iff$ $V=\emptyset$ or $\lvert X\setminus p^{-1}(V)\rvert < \kappa$.

Because $X\setminus p^{-1}(V) = p^{-1}(Y\setminus V)$, and because of standard facts relating closed and open sets and their preimages under a continuous function, the above is equivalent to:

> $C\subseteq Y$ is closed $\iff$ $C=Y$ or $\lvert p^{-1}(C)\rvert < \kappa$.

As $p$ can be any surjection $X\to Y$, it's difficult to say more that.

Comment: Thanks alot I really appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. I think that's the best characterization we can give, given the arbitrariness of $p$.

Comment: PS: Little "oops" — I added the corner-case clauses to the two highlighted lines: of course, $\emptyset$ is open, and $Y$ is closed.