# Is the following union connected

Tags: general-topology

For each $\omega \in J$ let $U_{\omega}$ be connected together with the fact that J is some well ordered index set set and that satisfies for each not minimal element M of J there is B of J such that B < M, and $U_B \cap U_M \neq \emptyset$.

Is $\bigcup_{\omega \in J} U_{\omega}$ connected?

Comment: Are $U_ω;~ω ∈ J$ open sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Suppose $U = \bigcup_{j\in J} U_j$ is not connected. Then $U = V \cup W$ for disjoint open sets $V,W$. For $j\in J$, we must have $U_j\subseteq V$ or $U_j\subseteq W$, for otherwise, $U\cap V, U\cap W$ covers $U$ with nonempty relatively open sets — impossible as $U_j$ is connected.

Let $J_V = \{j\in J\mid U_j\subseteq V\}$, $J_W = \{j\in J\mid U_j\subseteq W\}$. One of them, say $J_V$, contains $<$-least element of $J$. Let $j_0$ be the least element of $J_W$. Then by hypothesis, there is $i\in J$ with $i<j_0$ such that $U_i\cap U_{j_0}\ne \emptyset$. By definition of $j_0$, we must have $i\in J_V$. But then $U_i\cap U_{j_0} \subseteq V\cap W = \emptyset$ — contradiction.

Comment: can you help me in the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532677/final-topology-on-y?noredirect=1#comment3121680_1532677
I have been stuck on it since morning

Comment: I'll give it a look.